# Can't Find MacPorts (installed on OS 10.8.5

Tags: macports

How can I find MacPorts after it's been installed? I'm trying to use it to open GIMP but can't locate it. GIMP gave me the message "There is no application set to open the document fimp-2.8.14.dmg.torrent - so, that's why I downloaded MacPorts, and now I can't find THAT - Please Heeeeelp - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For run MacPort you have to write `sudo /opt/local/bin/port` in your Terminal window.

**Alias in .zshrc :**

```
alias port='sudo /opt/local/bin/port'
```

However, a .torrent file can be open with [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com) or [Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) without using MacPorts.

.torrent files explained : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file